# 'global' is undefined in ng-admin when compiling with webpack

Tags: webpack, ng-admin

I am new to webpack, and I am trying to migrate our project from rails assets pipeline to Webpack. When precompiling `ng-admin.min.js` with webpack, I am getting error that `Cannot set property 'rangy' of undefined` in the line `global.rangy = require('rangy');` in `ng-admin/src/javascripts/vendors.js` file.